# How to build a Map where the Key is an abstract base class (not Value)

Tags: c++, collections

I am trying to build a map of objects that are instances of various derived classes, with the base class being abstract:

```
class B {void SomeMethod() = 0;}; //abstract
class D1 : public B {...}; // not abstract
class D2 : public B {...}; // not abstract
std::unordered_map<B,int> myMap;

D1 * d1 = new D1();
D2 * d2 = new D2();
myMap.insert({*d1,5}
myMap.insert({*d2,8}
```

That does not work, because the map considers `*d1` a `B` object, and tries to copy-construct it inside the map. even if it would work, it would *slice* the object, and the D1-data would be lost. So far I understand why it can't work.

But how can I make such a map?

- storing `B*` pointers instead works fine, but then the hashing algorithm of the map compares *the pointers*, not the objects, which will not find a match
- I did not see a way to overwrite the = operator (and there really cannot be one, as the hashing algorithm works on the parameter, which is a pointer - I would have to overwrite the hashing algorithm itself to dereference the pointer.
- note that [C++ collection of abstract base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776993/c-collection-of-abstract-base-classes) is not a duplicate - it talks about the *Value*; I need the abstract base class as the *Key*, so I can *find()* it.

In other words, the **Question** is:
*How can I build a map of objects (and later search for them), where these objects are instances of different derived classes from a common base class?*

Comment: Store `std::unique_ptr<B>` (`B*` would work too, but it's ugly) and provide a custom hashing function?

Comment: basically, you want a map, where both e.g. the apple and the tomato map to e.g. red.

Does a multimap do you any good?

Comment: but I don't want to search by 'Red', but by 'Apple', and not by Apple's pointer, but by the full object 'Apple' and all its data.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I thought about that, but I didn't know you _can_ make a custom Hash function. Will look into that.

Comment: It's the third (optional) template parameter for `unordered_map`. (Alternatively, you could specialize `std::hash` for `unique_ptr<B>`.) Also apparently you have to provide an equality function too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, your second option is not possible. But your first is! Standard library containers let you use a custom hashing function, which you can use to your advantage.

Also, you would have needed to provide a custom hash function anyways, so it's shouldn't be an issue. Also you mentioned you wanted to be able to search them right? Well, the standard library also allows you to customize *that* too and you can provide a key equality object which would compare the underlying objects and not the pointers.

```
struct FooPtrHash {
  std::size_t operator()(const Foo *Value) const {
    return Value->Value;
  }
};

struct FooPtrEquality {
  bool operator()(const Foo *Lhs, const Foo *Rhs) const {
    return *Lhs == *Rhs;
  }
};

std::unordered_map<Foo*, int, FooPtrHash, FooPtrEquality> Map;
```

Comment: turns out the custom hash doesn't work for this case either, because it has the same issue - it won't compile the dereferencing of the base class pointer because it is abstract. - the custom Equality works though, and it's even better, because I can use different ones in different places, as it maps the ==operator according to the object types. Thanks!

Comment: @Aganju That's weird. [It works for me](https://godbolt.org/g/mhVR33). Maybe double check that you did everything right

Comment: I just found and fixed it. You are right, it works. I use `return sizeof(*Value);` in the `FooPtrHash` - not sure what you meant with Value->Value. But it is not only compiling, but also working correctly.

Comment: I think I see now. Value is the Hash-Value, which I still need to calculate. It's not simple the Value of the pair. But that's simple.

Comment: @Aganju Yeah, that was just a hash for my class. Your class would need to do something differently :)